# Download output (XML) from URL, then parse the XML to get the data?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to download the XML data outputted by Google Map API. After I download and store that data in a variable, I would like to parse that data to get a specific information. Here is the link to a sample output : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=34.6465583799,-101.57620022

```
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim sPageHTML  As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim XmlMapResponse As String


sURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + Selection.Value

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
XmlMapResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText
```

Once the XML data has been downloaded, I tried to parse out "**79088**" which is the postal code by doing this :

```
Dim strXML As String
Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

strXML = XmlMapResponse

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

If Not XDoc.LoadXML(strXML) Then
    Err.Raise XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , XDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xNode = XDoc.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name")

MsgBox xNode.InnerText(6)
```

I don't know why xNode.InnerText(6) doesn't work for me. In VB.NET it works fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectNodes returns a node list, not a single node.

Maybe you meant to use:

```
Set xNode = XDoc.SelectNodes( _
             "/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name")(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned SelectNodes returns a node list which caused an error when I attempted to run this code.You should either:

- change xNode to a IXMLDOMNodeList
- Select only a single node from the list (as suggested by Tim)
- Change the function to XDoc.selectSingleNode("/XPATH")

Beyond that, The IXMLDOMNode Object does not appear to support an InnerText function. use xNode.Text instead.

The following code runs without errors and returns the first result (8379)

```
Sub test()
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim sPageHTML  As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim XmlMapResponse As String

sURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + "34.6465583799,-101.57620022"

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
XmlMapResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim strXML As String
Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

strXML = XmlMapResponse

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

If Not XDoc.LoadXML(strXML) Then
    Err.Raise XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , XDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name")

MsgBox xNode.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: This returns just the street number. What I'm looking for is the ZIP code, or postal code, which is 77564 (using the link in that code).