# Unable to Access .cfm or XML via HTTP Request in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, http, rss

I am trying to access the RSS feeds from "https://www.higheredjobs.com/rss/". there are several ".cfm" links. when I try to access the link "https://www.higheredjobs.com/rss/articleFeed.cfm". it gives me error "The system cannot locate the resource specified". however it can be opened in the  browser, which contain html with xml.
I need the data from the xml into the excel. but first thing first I cannot access either the .cfm or xml by http request using VBA.

Could anyone please help me understand why I am unable to access the .cfm or XML file using an HTTP request in VBA? Is there an alternative method to retrieve the XML data from this source?

```
Sub ParseHTMLtoXML2()
    Dim url As String
    Dim xmlHTTP As Object
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Dim rssElement As Object
    Dim channelElement As Object
    Dim itemElements As Object
    
    url = "https://www.higheredjobs.com/rss/articleFeed.cfm"
    
    Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHTTP.send
    
    '//*[@id="webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml"]/rss/channel/item[1]

    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText
    
    Set rssElement = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rss")(0)
    
    Set channelElement = rssElement.getElementsByTagName("channel")(0)
    
    Set itemElements = channelElement.getElementsByTagName("item")
    
    Dim item As Object
    For Each item In itemElements
        MsgBox item.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText
    Next item
    
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
    Set htmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If your URL returns XML then it would probably be best to parse that XML using MSXML instead of treating it like it's HTML.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519320/download-output-xml-from-url-then-parse-the-xml-to-get-the-data and other similar posts here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the link to xml. but my actual problem is loading the page which is not happening using `xmlhttp`. as soon as I grab the xml or even html, I can parse it to get the my info. same goes for the other `WinHttp`. page is not loading. maybe its matter of certification (TLS 1.x), but internet properties shows all checked.

Comment: Works fine for me: `xmlHTTP.responseText` returns the expected XML.

Comment: let me recheck and try it on another win10. maybe its win7 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a powershell script to convert to csv.  It may be better to make output tab delimited instead of comma.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$csv = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$uri = 'https://www.higheredjobs.com/rss/articleFeed.cfm'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($uri)
$atomNs = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('atom')

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($csv)
$header = 'title,description,link,language,copyright,managingEditor,atom link'
$writer.WriteLine($header)
foreach($item in $doc.Descendants('item'))
{
   $title = '"' + $item.Element('title').Value + '"'
   $description = '"' + $item.Element('description').Value + '"'
   $link = '"' + $item.Element('link').Value + '"'
   $language = '"' + $item.Element('language').Value + '"'
   $copyright = '"' + $item.Element('copyright').Value + '"'
   $managingEditor = '"' + $item.Element('managingEditor').Value + '"'
   $atomLink = '"' + $item.Element($atomNs + 'link').Value + '"'
   $writer.Writeline([string]::Join(',',@($title,$description,$link,$language,$copyright,$managingEditor,$atomLink)))
}
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This will make it more complicated, while distribution, I was actually looking for MS Excel solution.

Comment: There is no reason in this case the data cannot be extracted in the VBA macro.  The data is xml and embedded in an html response.  XML and HTML are very similar, but HTML libraries will not always work on XML data.